# VS Code - HTML Editor - Disable closing tag cursor (mirror cursor)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When editing HTML files in VS Code, and putting the keyboard cursor in the opening tag, a 2nd cursor appear in the closing tag.

How can I disable this feature?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is standard behaviour? I don't got this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature called **HTML mirror cursor** and it was introduce in v1.41.1 - Novermber 2019.

To disable it, in your `settings.json` add this line

```
  "html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag": false
```

You can read more about it at: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_html-mirror-cursor

### Update

Starting from version 1.44  - March 2020, the mirror cursor feature was renamed to **Synced Regions**. 
The old settings key is now deprecated. From this version you need to use:

```
  "editor.renameOnType": false
```

You can read more about it at: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44#_synced-regions

Answer (score 0):

Beginning version 1.52, this setting is now called `editor.linkedEditing`: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52